# How to end chained http requests in RxJava Vert.x?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, vert.x

How to end chained requests in Rx Vert.X ?

```
 HttpClient client = Vertx.vertx().createHttpClient();
        HttpClientRequest request = client.request(HttpMethod.POST,
                "someURL")
                .putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .putHeader("content-length", Integer.toString(jsonData.length())).write(jsonData);
        request.toObservable().
                //flatmap HttpClientResponse -> Observable<Buffer>
                        flatMap(httpClientResponse -> { //something
                    return httpClientResponse.toObservable();
                }).
                        map(buffer -> {return buffer.toString()}).
                //flatmap data -> Observable<HttpClientResponse>
                        flatMap(postData -> client.request(HttpMethod.POST,
                        someURL")
                        .putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .putHeader("content-length", Integer.toString(postData.length())).write(postData).toObservable()).
                //flatmap HttpClientResponse -> Observable<Buffer>
                        flatMap(httpClientResponse -> {
                    return httpClientResponse.toObservable();
                })......//other operators
request.end();
```

Notice that I have .`end()` for the top request. How do I end request that is inside of the .`flatmap` ? Do I even need to end it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like the following code.

The main idea is that you don't directly use the `HttpClientRequest` as obtained by the `Vertx` client. Instead you create another flowable that will invoke `end()` as soon as the first subscription is received.

Here, for instance, you can obtain the request through a pair custom methods: in this case `request1()` and `request2()`. They both use `doOnSubscribe()` to trigger the `end()` you need. [Read its description on the ReactiveX page](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html).

This examle uses **vertx** and **reactivex**, I hope you could use this set up.

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.http.HttpClient;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.http.HttpClientRequest;
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.http.HttpClientResponse;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StackOverflow {

    @Test public void test(){

        Buffer jsonData = Buffer.buffer("..."); // the json data.

        HttpClient client = Vertx.vertx().createHttpClient(); // the vertx client.

        request1(client)
            .flatMap(httpClientResponse -> httpClientResponse.toFlowable())
            .map(buffer -> buffer.toString())
            .flatMap(postData -> request2(client, postData) )
            .forEach( httpResponse -> {
                // do something with returned data);
            });

    }

    private Flowable<HttpClientResponse> request1(HttpClient client) {
        HttpClientRequest request = client.request(HttpMethod.POST,"someURL");
        return request
                .toFlowable()
                .doOnSubscribe( subscription -> request.end() );
    }

    private Flowable<HttpClientResponse> request2(HttpClient client, String postData) {
        HttpClientRequest request = client.request(HttpMethod.POST,"someURL");
        // do something with postData
        return request
                .toFlowable()
                .doOnSubscribe( subscription -> request.end() );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to ensure to call `request.end()`. But I would dig into documentation of Vert.x or just open source code if there is one, to see if it does call end() for you. Otherwise one could be

```
final HttpClientRequest request = ...
request.toObservable()
       .doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
           @Override
           public void call() {
               request.end();
           }
       });
```